# Default modelbinding for enum in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How do I bind the value of radio button, generated with the `Html.RadioButton()` HTML helper, to a field that has a struct as type?

Less abstract:

CommonProject.Services.SearchBag.Effects:

```
public enum Effects
{
    Any,
    Solid,
    Effect
}
```

In the strongly typed ViewData:

```
public class SearchBag{    
    public Effects EffectIndicator { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view (this doesn't really work):

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("SearchBag.EffectIndicator", "Any", ViewData.Model.SearchBag.EffectIndicatorIsAny, new { @id = "SearchBag.EffectIndicatorAny" })%>
```

**UPDATE**
It seems to work once..
Initially it creates the radiobuttons as desired, then when you change the value and post back, the value is correctly bound. Then on regenerating the page, all values of the buttons are set to the value you chose earlier on.

Comment: Are you rebinding your viewdata after the action is executed? Also, are you setting the isChecked parameter of the RadioButton Helper?

Answer (score 1):

If your View is strongly typed with SearchBag as your View Data Class then you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.EffectIndicator, "Any", new { @id = "SearchBag.EffectIndicatorAny" }) %>
```

Then when your View form is submitted back to the Controller, it would look something like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod(SearchBag searchBag)
    {
        Effects selectedEffect = searchBag.EffectIndicator;
    }
}
```

Does that help?